# How does an allocator work with std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++17

I was looking at the documentation for [vector::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) on cppreference, and as an exercise, was trying to figure out how I'd implement `explicit vector( const Allocator& alloc ) noexcept;`

The question I found asking myself was, why would you pass an Allocator to the vector?  It would only make sense if the Allocator was polymorphic.  However, if that group of allocators have different state info, i.e. have different sizes, this causes the following issues:

1. You can't just have a allocator as a member/base class, as you would cause the object to be sliced when copied.
2. If you don't have it as a member, it would have to be allocated.  Allocation implies that it can cause an exception.

So, given those reasons, does that mean that the group of allocators must have state only in the base class?  Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you don't have it as a member, it would have to be allocated.
>   Allocation implies that it can cause an exception.

No, it doesn't have to be allocated. To construct an instance of `std::vector` it only needs to be copy-constructed.

The allocator instance gets passed as a `const` reference to `std::vector`'s constructor. The `std::vector` itself has an instance of `Allocator` as a (private) class member, and it is copy-constructed from this parameter.

Keep in mind that `Allocator` is the second (defaulted) `std::vector` template parameter. As such, a typical implementation declares `Allocator` as a (private) member of `std::vector` itself, so the only allocation that occurs is the allocation of `std::vector` itself.

The default constructor of `std::vector` default-constructs its `Allocator` class member, which is also `noexcept` (as of C++17).

So the capsule summary is that the allocator class (as of C++17) must have a `noexcept` copy constructor, and a `noexcept` default constructor, it order to meet the `noexcept` exception requirement of `std::vector` itself.

There is no requirement for *additional* allocation to occur as part of constructing an instance of `std::vector` (for constructors that don't initialize the contents of `std::vector` as part of its construction) -- excepting the allocation of the `std::vector` itself.